# How can I check the speed and strength of site visitors computer?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have made some pretty resource-intensive items on my new site's design, and I'm a bit concerned. While testing on different computers, I notice some simply cannot handle the computer generated art/animations nor 1080p video. This could be a problem.

So I'm already planning to test their Internet speed (or at least, that it's sufficient) using a "control file" and timing the response, but how can I (or what would be the best way) to do so for checking hardware?

So far I have:

1. Use a short 1080p video, test the time to download. Test start-finish time, see if there's lag.
2. Use a loading page with 2 gateways: one for regular, one for enhanced. Above the "door" to enhanced, have some heavy javascript animation - if it lags, they should click 'regular
   '.

   **loading page will likely be cookie-dependent overlay, don't want to send them to home page from search.*

I'm not wild about either of those ideas, and I already strip the resource-intensive items for sizes under 700 or so. Kind of a "why should some suffer for others lacking" deal. Eventually all computers can handle it, but I can't be freezing their devices just to put on a good show.

**Update**

3 . Have an "awesome" page that records the destination URL, does some fast JS animation (totaling under 3 seconds), and says "testing device capabilities" then "proceed to site". This would automatically determine the best version and give them something cool to look at while it's testing.

Comment: Suggestion 2 sounds just terrible from a UX point of view. It will also not work because people click what they find interesting. "Enhanced" sounds way cooler than regular.

Comment: I was also afraid of that. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514332/website-performance-testing-how-best-to-approximate-computer-performance?rq=1 which has some interesting suggestions, but I'm still open to more. This post *is* 2 years old after all.

Comment: I guess the only option really is to either make your Javascript magic a lot faster (use hardware rendering or something if you don't) or leave it away altogether. Even the users with high-end systems won't be happy if your website eats away their battery power for no good reason. Websites just shouldn't use a lot of resources

Comment: Hmm.. I agree to a point. It doesn't strain my system at all, nor very much for any device I've tested on that was made in the last 2 years. The site focuses on design and 'cutting edge' web technology. That unfortunately means lag for older systems. I'm not exactly trying to "have my cake and eat it too", simply wanting to offer users a sugar-free version and maybe automatically check for diabetes ;)

Comment: Well I guess it's a different story if the visual presentation is an important part of the content.